# How do I introduce a Delay in Camel to prevent file locking before the files are copied in?

Tags: apache-camel, jms

I am using Camel, ActiveMq, and JMS to poll a directory and process any files it finds.  The problem with larger files is they start processing before being fully copied into the directory.  I has assumed (yes, I know what assume gets you) that the file system would prevent it -- but that doesn't seem to be true.  The examples in the Camel docs do not seem to be working.  Here is my code from within the configure method of the RouteBuilder:

```
    from("file://" + env.getProperty("integration.directory.scan.add.eng.jobslist")+"?consumer.initialDelay=100000")
        .doTry()
            .setProperty("servicePath").constant("/job")
            .setProperty("serviceMethod").constant("POST")
            .process("engImportJobsFromFileProcessor")
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .to("log:-- Add Job(s) Error -------------------------")
            .choice()
                .when(constant(env.getProperty("eng.mail.enabled.flag.add.jobslist.yn")).isEqualToIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    .setHeader("subject", constant(env.getProperty("integration.mq.topic.add.eng.jobslist.error.email.subject")))
                    .to("direct://email.eng")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("log:-----------------------------------------")
                    .to("log:-- Email for JOBSLIST IS DISABLED")
                    .to("log:-----------------------------------------")
            .end()
        .end()
        .log("Finished loading jobs from file ")
    ;
```

As you can see, I tried to set an 'initialDelay', I have also tried 'delay' and 'readLock=changed' and nothing made a difference.  As soon as the file hits the directory, Camel starts processing.  All I am after is a nice simple delay before the file is polled.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `readLockMinAge`.

From [File2 component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html):

> This option allows you to specify a minimum age a file must be before attempting to acquire the read lock. For example, use `readLockMinAge=300s` to require that the file is at least 5 minutes old.

For 100s delay could URI look like this:

```
from("file://" + env.getProperty("integration.directory.scan.add.eng.jobslist")+"?readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=100s")
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but it doesn't work.  The file with the lock causes an immediate error regardless of options.

Comment: Strange. I have tested it and works as expected. Which error do you get? Which Camel version? And which JDK? Is it possible that your JVM is using different time/timezone than operating system? Meybe you could test it on different machine?

Comment: Camel 2.18, JDK and JRE are 1.8.0_151, Tomcat 8.5.29.  The error is:
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[] with value [Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\DISCUS-NG-files-dev\integration\import\jobs\export.csv]] due java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Comment: I have tried to use the 'done' option, assuming as a last resort the user could upload a 'done' file to delay processing until they are sure the data file is loaded, but even with that option enabled and no 'done' file in the directory, the file still get the error due to it being locked.  Even just copying in a simple file, it starts processing without the 'done' file in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of the options "readLock=changed" , "readLockCheckInterval=1000" and readLockMinAge=20s
(1000 is in milliseconds and the default value, should be changed to higher value is writes are slower i.e the file size changes after a long time, this may happen on certain filesystems, that the file size changes not very frequently while transfer is in process)

The file component documentation @ http://camel.apache.org/file2.html says

**for readlock=changed**

> changed is using file length/modification timestamp to detect whether the file is currently being copied or not. Will at least use 1 sec. to determine this, so this option cannot consume files as fast as the others, but can be more reliable as the JDK IO API cannot always determine whether a file is currently being used by another process. The option readLockCheckInterval can be used to set the check frequency.

**for readLockCheckInterval=1000**

> Camel 2.6: Interval in milliseconds for the read-lock, if supported by the read lock. This interval is used for sleeping between attempts to acquire the read lock. For example when using the changed read lock, you can set a higher interval period to cater for slow writes. The default of 1 sec. may be too fast if the producer is very slow writing the file.

**for readLockMinAge=20s**

> Camel 2.15: This option applies only to readLock=change. This option allows you to specify a minimum age a file must be before attempting to acquire the read lock. For example, use readLockMinAge=300s to require that the file is at least 5 minutes old. This can speedup the poll when the file is old enough as it will acquire the read lock immediately.

So in the end your endpoint should look something like

from("file://" + env.getProperty("integration.directory.scan.add.eng.jobslist")+"?consumer.initialDelay=100000&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1000&readLockMinAge=20s")

Comment: Tried it, and even cut&pasted your suggestion and all I get is an error if the file is locked:
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[] with value [Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\DISCUS-NG-files-dev\integration\import\jobs\export.csv]] due java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Comment: May I know more about the process that is copying the file to this directory .? Also what values of readLockCheckInterval and readLockMinAge did you use ?

Comment: It's built into camel, as soon as the file errors due to being locked, camel sends it to the .camel file.  Which is weird to me because the file shouldn't be movable due to the lock . . . or so I thought.  The values I used included the ones in your suggestion.

Comment: New information, for some reason the optional tags are running fine when run within Intellij for testing, but when I deploy to Tomcat (same instance used by Intellij) the options are ignored.  This is on a local server and a remote one, so two different instances.  Head scratcher for sure.

Comment: What size are the files usually ? and how much time does it take to transfer ? Can you update readLockCheckInterval=1000&readLockMinAge=20s to be more than the time required to copy. Just trying out here.

Comment: Also I would like to know how do you copy file to this directory ? ftp ? another camel route ? and what file system is this (ext3/4, is it a network share ? )

Comment: Also another thing I would like you to try is readLock=rename and removing the other options.

Answer (score 1):

OK, turned out to be a combination of things.  First off I test inside of IntelliJ and also outside for several reasons -- one is a security issue with using email within IDEA.  Tomcat, outside of IntelliJ was picking up a classes folder in the webapps/ROOT directory, which was overwriting my changes to the uri options.  That's what was driving me nuts.  That ROOT folder had been there from a deployment error from several months ago.  But it wasn't being picked up by IntelliJ even though I was using the same Tomcat instance. That's why it appear that my changes were being ignored.